# Using jQuery/javascript to automatically center a div that is bigger than the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, centering

I've been having some trouble making a div that is 1920px in width auto-center on the website. 
Right now i've been using this jQuery code to auto center the div when the page gets opened:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider();

    var extra= 1920 - $(window).width(); 
    var extraleftside= extra/2;
    $("div#scroller").css("left", "-" + extraleftside + "px");
});
</script>
```

But that code only adjusts when the website is refreshed, is it possible to make it do it in real time?

If you want to see the effect i want, it is the same as the scrolling background in this site: http://www.apps.no

LeGEC answered this quite nice, this code did the trick:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider();

    var extra= 1920 - $(window).width(); 
    var extraleftside= extra/2;
    $("div#scroller").css("left", "-" + extraleftside + "px");
}


);

$(window).bind("resize", resizeWindow);
function resizeWindow( e ) {
    var extra= 1920 - $(window).width(); 
    var extraleftside= extra/2;
    $("div#scroller").css("left", "-" + extraleftside + "px");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't help, since the object is wider than the window, so it will stop centering at the left of the screen like this: http://i.imgur.com/Jjb5cfU.jpg

Comment: By "doing it in real time", do you mean you want the `<div>` size to change when the window is resized?

Comment: OP want to center a div that is bigger then window, `margin: 0 auto;`, wont do that

Comment: No, the div size should stay the same, since it is bigger than the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean recalculating it on [resize](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) ?

```
function doResize(){
    var extra= 1920 - $(window).width(); 
    var extraleftside= extra/2;
    $("div#scroller").css("left", "-" + extraleftside + "px");
}

$(window).load(function(){
    // maybe the slider should also be updated on resize...
    $('#slider').nivoSlider();

    doResize();
});

$(function(){
    $(window).resize(doResize);
});
```

Comment: Almost complete answer - I would however chain the `resize()` event, i.e. `$(window).resize(doResize).resize();`, so that the event is fired when the page first loads, too :)

Comment: YES! Added a listener with this and it did the trick! Thank you!

Comment: @Terry : added, and probably do it on `$(window).load()`